# Invoking a public method of public class from a class in different package

Tags: java

I am trying to invoke a public method of a class in a different package. 
I have already imported the package so that's not the problem. I am using eclipse and it is giving me errors mentioned below.

Code:

```
public class BookView extends LinearLayout
   implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener
   {
   private static final String LOGTAG = "BookView";
   private EPubWebView afd_webView;
   private Context afd_curContext;
  private FrameLayout afd_tableContentView;
  private String afd_cachePath = "";
  private EPubDriver afd_epubDriver;
  private AdView adView;
  private int currentPageNum = 1;
  private int totalPages;
  private int current_chapter;
  private int current_percent;
  private int pIndex;
  private int sIndex;
  private int size;
  private int chapterSize;
  private int bookSize;
  private String clickBk;
  private String bookPath;
  private String mDir = "/sdcard";
  private List<Map<String, Object>> mDataList;
  private ListView bookListView;
  private Handler handler = new Handler();
  private PopupWindow mBooksWindow;
  private int andVersion;
  private TextToSpeech tts;
  private final String errorMessage = "Download Error!";
  private boolean downloadCancel = false;
  private boolean isDownloading = false;

  public BookView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
  {
    super(context, attrs);
    setOrientation(1);
    this.afd_curContext = context;
    this.handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
    BookView.this.doAdMob();
      }
    }
    , 10000L);

    this.tts = new TextToSpeech(context, this);

    this.afd_webView = new EPubWebView(context);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
      .getMetrics(metrics);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context
  .getSystemService("layout_inflater");
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.afd_bookview, this);
    init();
  }

  public void jsImportBook(String epubBookPath) {
  if (!BookView.this.importBook(epubBookPath))
    return;
  BookView.this.createBookshelf();
}
}
```

Is the below invocation method correct?

```
 public void importnewbook(String epubBookPath) {

BookView v = new BookView();
    result = v.jsImportBook(epubBookPath); 
}
```

Errors i am getting:
1)The constructor BookView() is undefined
2)The method jsImportBook(String) is undefined for the type BookView

Comment: Are you sure you are importing the right definition for `BookView`?

Comment: The method is void, cannot return a boolean and apparently your class doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: paste the complete code. Looks like trivial issue.

Comment: You shouldn't be required to create a constructor but why don't you create one in your BookView Class and see what happens. Make sure you make the change mentioned by Soririos above.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That boolean was my stupid mistake. Sorry.

Comment: @Susie The BookView.class is in a jar file and hence i cannot modify it in any way.

Comment: @Bhavyanshu Use a different constructor, one that your imported class does have. And doesn't assign the method invocation to any variable.

Comment: Would you mind including the package statements for both classes and the imports for your calling class (the one that has the `importnewbook` method?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that by default the compiler will add a no-args constructor if you haven't supplied any yourself.

But if you add one, let's say that takes a String then the compiler assumes you know what you are doing and takes no action. Which means you won't have a no-args constructor, if you want one you need to define it.

In short:

1) Do nothing and you get a no-args constructor.
2) Add any constructor and that's all you have, compiler adds nothing else.

And of course always check that the methods you defined return the type you expect.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your import statement.
2. Do you have any parametrized constructor in your class ? If yes, add a default constructor.

I can see that your class has a parametrized constructor. So, in this case no default constructor will be created for you. You will have to write one on your own in order to write new BookView().